# During the Episode 1 prologue, is it possible to not fall from a branch?

Tags: jurassic-park-2011

During the Episode 1 Prologue, you fall off a cliff and grab a tree branch.  This results in a quick-time event where you have to press the same button repeatedly to avoid falling.  However, whenever I try, the branch breaks before the meter is full.

Is it possible to press one of the buttons fast enough to avoid falling, or is the falling part unavoidable?

Comment: The first thing I thought of when you posted this question was "You don't fall from a branch in the Skyrim prologue..."

Answer (score 1):

The falling part is unavoidable. While playing on the Steam version, I used my controller's turbo mode and still fell. There is also no [achievement](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/JurassicPark/achievements) for preventing the fall. The fall also has no impact on obtaining any of the achievements.